# How to map an object inside a string to set using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, java-8, jackson

I am converting a String to Pojo using Jackson ObjectMapper.

My incoming message:

```
{
    "countryCode": "US",
    "skuNumber": "TEST",
    "itemTaxCd": "89999",
    "lastModifiedBy": "xyz"
}
```

Method :

```
public void processImsProductTaxEvents(String event) {
    try {
        SkuMasterDTO message = objectMapper.readValue(event, SkuMasterDTO.class);
        log.debug("Received message from IMS", message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error in Object Mapper converting String to TaxCodeDTO", e);
    }
}
```

Now countryCode is inside CountryDTO inside SkuMasterDTO defined as a Set

```
private Set<CountryDTO> countries = new HashSet<>();
```

CountryDTO class

```
public class CountryDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 2)
    private String countryCode;
```

I am trying to set the countryCode to the set **without changing the input Json**. Any suggestions?

Comment: for that you need input json something like , `{
    "countries" : {"countryCode": "US"},
    "skuNumber": "TEST",
    "itemTaxCd": "89999",
    "lastModifiedBy": "xyz"
}`

Comment: Client sends it in that format, So I don't wanna ask for a change on their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAYS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) in your `ObjectMapper` instance. Then you must change the json field `countryCode` to `countries` or mark `Set countries` as json property `countryCode` using `@JsonProperty` and provide a constructor/factory method within `String` parameter. This will make your object mapper behave as per your requirements.

Comment: Not at all,the answer is very nice.I just added something to describe how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define countryCode inside SkuMasterDTO class.

You can add a getter and build a set

```
Set<CountryDTO> getCountries(){
    Set<CountryDTO> countries = new HashSet<>();
    countries.add(new CountryDTO(countryCode));
    return countries;
}
```

Or you can prepare set inside set method.